# SDL_KEYDOWN not working, got code 771 instead

Tags: c++, sdl

Here is my code:

```
void MainGame::ProcessInput()
    {SDL_Event Evnt;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&Evnt));
        {switch(Evnt.type)
            {case SDL_QUIT:         {_GameState = GameState::EXIT;}
            break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:   {}
            break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:       {_InputManager.PressedKey(Evnt.key.keysym.scancode);}
            break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:         {_InputManager.ReleasedKey(Evnt.key.keysym.scancode);}
            break;
            case 771:               {std::cout << "Info1 = " << Evnt.key.keysym.scancode << std::endl;
                                    _InputManager.PressedKey(Evnt.key.keysym.scancode); }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So in this code, if I push up, down, left and right arrows, KEYDOWN is working properly.  If I hit any letters on my keyboard, it will only return code 771.  Here I made a test including 771 in my switch.  When I hit letters, it does go to 771 and print a silly number like 30445778.  And this number change every time I re-run the program.  Man what's going on here?!?  please help me

Comment: As a first step, I'd propose to remove `;` after your while condition.

Comment: There ya go!  That was a funny mistake!  Didn't see it.  Thank you very much it work perfectly now.

Comment: It's strange that the compiler didn't see that

Comment: I'll elaborate in the answer below.

Comment: Actually not that strange, it's a valid code! But ya, worth a warning, hopping someone look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is an additional `;` after your `while` condition. Citing [SDL wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent), your code should be written as follows:

```
while (1) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        /* handle your event here */
    }
    /* do some other stuff here -- draw your app, etc. */
}
```

Note that there's no semicolon after `while`.

However, although the code you've written does not do what you want it to do, it's still correct from C++ point of view.

This line:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&Evnt));
```

will enter a loop that will iterate up until the point `SDL_PollEvent` returns `0`, while doing nothing.

After that, your `switch` statement will only run once, processing the last polled event (disregarding its type). In the same time, your `switch` statement is not ready to handle most of the event types.